# .htaccess does not work in local?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website and i want to remove .html extension from pages. this is my .htaccess file

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]     
order deny,allow
```

but it does not work. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you activated mod_rewrite in apache?